# How do I modify the smartctl scan list on ubuntu?

Tags: smartctl

I removed 2 external usb drives and replaced them with internal drives via sata cables to the motherboard.
And now every day I get  2 emails from smartctl saying that the two external drives are missing.
That's all fine and good, but I know that, I disconnected them on purpose.
For the life of me I can't find where smartctl is getting the list of drives to scan from.
There's nothing in /dev/ there's nothing in /etc/smart* nothing anywhere.
Where is the list that smartctl is deriving the scan list to send warning emails from?

Answer (score 0):

In principle `smartd` uses the definition in `/etc/smartd.conf` for `DEVICESCAN`, or hard-coded disk paths from `/dev/` if you added those. So removed disks should normally automatically be skipped.

It may help to remove the state file for those drives in `/var/lib/smartmontools/`.

Comment: didn't work. I cleared out all the relevant files from /var/lib/smartmontools and I'm still getting the emails. Can't imagine where from.